# Galois groups and free products

Tags: galois-theory

This question comes from trying to better understand the generalisation of the following past exam question:

[image: exam question]

The interesting case here is $G_2$: we see that the Galois group of $x^2+1$ is $C_2$ (corresponding to complex conjugation) and the Galois group of $x^3-3x+1$ is $A_3\cong C_3$ (by the hint mainly).
Now we can see how these two groups interact with each other by embedding them in $S_5$.
We label the roots $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_5$, with the first two being roots of $x^2+1$ and the last three being roots of $x^3-3x+1$, and labeled such that $\alpha_4$ and $\alpha_5$ are both conjugate to each other.
Then $$G_2\cong\langle(12)(45),(345)\rangle$$ (or so I think... it's very likely that I'm wrong!)

My question is though, what can we say about $G_2$ without having to embed it directly in $S_5$?
We know that is must be isomorphic to $S_3$ since it is order $6$ and non-abelian, but it seems intuitive that we should be able to write $G_2$ as some kind of product of $C_2$ and $C_3$, in particular maybe some kind of free product (fibered coproduct).

**TL;DR: What can we say about the Galois group of a product of irreducible polynomials in terms of their individual Galois groups?**

Comment: "Free product" is a very different thing in group theory than what you describe in your question. I think you may possibly want "direct product" or even "semidirect product"

Comment: You will get the direct product, iff the splitting fields of the two factors are *linearly disjoint*, iff they intersect trivially. I once needed to write up [a quick and dirty introduction to linearly disjoint extensions](http://users.utu.fi/lahtonen/linearly_disjoint.pdf). IIRC Pete L. Clark has something more comprehensive on-line. Couldn't find it right away. If the two splitting fields don't intersect trivially, then the total Galois group will be smaller. This happens for example with $f_3(x)=(x^3-2)(x^3-3)$ because both factors bring in the cubic roots of unity.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks, that's pretty helpful stuff, but now I'd really like to hear some more about the case where the splitting fields have non-trivial intersection! What can we say about the Galois group then? It seems like we should be able to say something about its presentation in terms of generators and relations of the two Galois groups of the factors

Comment: @Timbuc I wasn't too sure what kind of product would arise. I first guessed some kind of semidirect product, but it seemed that it might be some kind of (amalgamated) free product instead, because we're kind of taking both sets of generators and keeping their individual relations, but maybe adding some more. I'm not that great at all this stuff, but I've been learning about the Seifert van-Kampen theorem and this seemed to have just a slightly similar air about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually stumbled across [these](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/galoiscorrthms.pdf) notes by Keith Conrad which answer exactly the kind of questions that I was asking without really knowing how to phrase them.
All of his expository papers are really great actually, and I highly recommend them!